# Plotly/Dash adjust Height of Trace Container

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

How can I ONLY adjust the height of the inner trace container?

I am aware that I can generally change the height of the graph [setting-graph-size](https://plotly.com/python/setting-graph-size/) but this also includes axis labels and the legend.

Also it came to my notice that the bigger the legend gets, the smaller the trace container gets.

Maybe use the example stated in the docu linked above:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", facet_col="sex",
                 width=800, height=400)

fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=20),
    paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue",
)

fig.show()
```

[image]